# Diagonal background css without image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a diagonal background with CSS.

Why not use images? Because I want to make a parallax effect later and I can not do it with images due to some factors.

You can see here the page:

http://jsfiddle.net/2ABd4/6/

As you can see, the result is the one I want. The problem is that the layer named "bg1" and "bg2" have a fixed position.

```
position: fixed;
```

I do not want it to be fixed.
But if I put an absolute position is off to the right.

So, I need this result  to remain diagonal, without being fixed without dislodging the page to the right. The question is: Is it possible to do this?

Comment: The absolute position works for me on FF24

Comment: I notice some IE specific styles in the fiddle. What versions do you need to support ? Some amazing things are possible with css3 gradients so this might be another option for you ?